# Finding top similar strings in PHP?

Tags: php

I have an array of 17,000 strings. Many of the strings have similar matches, for example:

> ```
> User Report XYZ123
> Bob Smith
> User Report YEI723
> User Report
> User Report
> Number of Hits 27
> Frank's Weekly Transaction Report
> Transaction Report 123
> ```

What is the best way to find the top "similar strings"? For instance, using the example above, I would want to see "User Report" and "Transaction Report" as two of the top "similar strings".

Comment: Shouldn't the "most similar" be instead "Frank's Weekly Transaction Report" and "Transaction Report 123"?

Comment: A crude method would be to use `levenshtein()` to determine the distance between two strings.

Answer (score 0):

Without giving you all the source code to do this, you could go through the array and remove components you consider useless, like any letters with numbers, and so on.

Then you can use `array_count_values()` and sort that array to see the top ones involved.

Answer (score 0):

You could compute the [Levenstein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) for each string compared with others and then sort them by that value.

```
$strings = array('str1', 'str2', 'car', 'dog', 'apple', 'house', 'str3');
$len = count($strings);

$distances = array_fill(0, $len, 0);

for($i=0; $i<$len-1; ++$i)
    for($j=$i+1; $j<$len; ++$j)
    {
        $dist = levenshtein($strings[$i], $strings[$j]);
        $distances[$i] += $dist;
        $distances[$j] += $dist;
    }

// Here $distances indicates how of "similar" is each string
// The lower values are more "similar"
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could do a foreach through each of the strings and eliminate the ones that you don't want for that particular search. Then go through the once you have left (possibly with another foreach) and keep shrinking the number of strings that you have an interest in down until there are just a few. Then sort those by something like alphabetical order.

Answer (score -1):

If you are able to get all the strings as an array and loop them in a `foreach()` like this:

```
$string_array = array('string', 'string1', 'string2', 'does-not-match');
$needle = 'string';

$results = array();
foreach($string_array as $key => $val):
    if (fnmatch($needle, $val):
        $results[] = $val;
    endif;
endforeach;
```

in the end you should end having the entries that match `$needle`. As alternative to `fnmatch()` you could use `preg_match()` and as pattern `/string/i`

```
$string_array = array('string', 'string1', 'string2', 'does-not-match');
$needle = '/string/i';

$results = array();
foreach($string_array as $key => $val):
    if (!empty(preg_match($needle, $val)):
        $results[] = $val;
    endif;
endforeach;
```

Note there could be issues when using empty() and pass the result of preg_match().:

> **Prior to PHP 5.5, empty() only supports variables; anything else will result in a parse error. In other words, the following will not work: empty(trim($name)). Instead, use trim($name) == false.**

No errors should be issued with PHP version 5.3.x < 5.4

Comment: Why `fnmatch`? That's terrible. Might as well use `md5` :s

Comment: `fnmatch() checks if the passed string would match the given shell wildcard pattern.` from the PHP manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.fnmatch.php
Which makes the `fnmatch()` equivalent to the `preg_match()`

Comment: The input is plain text, there are no regular expressions. What if one of the input strings is `".*"` that doesn't look like `"string"` at all.

Comment: Well as in every application and in every case, user input should be sanitised as appropriate. *For instance, using the example above, I would want to see "User Report" and "Transaction Report" as two of the top "similar strings".* the OP says what he wants and if the `$needle` is **User Report** the result should contain the 4 entries that are in the example data. Which makes your comments unnecessary and irrelative.

Comment: How do you get from `User Report` to `Transaction Report` with a regular expression? My point is, your answer makes no sense and your solution is not what OP wants. He want to match the input strings against themselves. So basically an O-squared algorithm.

Comment: Well you might have a point there. I had to read the question a couple of times, and I realised that the user wants to fetch the similarity between all the strings. Which really makes my answer irrelevant. Ty for the tipo. :)